# Rails Tutorial Ch 12 exercise 2 - what to compare when Escaping HTML content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

just need a hint for this template

```
test "feed on Home page" do
  get root_path
    @user.feed.paginate(page: 1).each do |micropost|
    assert_match CGI.escapeHTML(FILL_IN), FILL_IN
  end
end
```

i inserted it with micropost.content but still not sure for the next param
for this code:

```
assert_match CGI.escapeHTML(micropost.content), 'something?'
```

i still can`t figure it out what is something is. it should not be a micropost.content too right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out, we only need to insert response.body for the second params to assert each of the micropost is exist for the HTML content

```
assert_match CGI.escapeHTML(micropost.content), response.body
```